# handle notification in background fcm flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm going crazy, looking for a way to make background notifications appear. I have tried various ways but to no avail. I use firebase_messaging 7.0.3. i'm just trying for ios. If something works, please help

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onBackgroundMessage: _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      _showNotification(message);
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onLaunch: $message");
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume: $message");
    },
  );

Future<dynamic>_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(Map<String,dynamic> message) {
print("FCM backgroundMessageHandler $message");
_showNotification(message);
return Future<void>.value();}

Future _showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
print("INI NOTIF $message");
await _localNotifications.show(
  ++_count,
  message['title'],
  message['body'],
  platformChannelSpecifics,
);
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you post that code?

Comment: Which platform? What do you mean by appear? Are you not seeing the messages come through at all or are they just not being shown?

Comment: @nvoigt the coding is in question

Comment: @rmtmckenzie in IOS, not seeing the messages come through at all

Comment: Where did you put that code (can you maybe provide an [mcve]) and how do you send messages?

Comment: oh. One thing to be aware of is that iOS very severely limits the amount of messages you can receive... they say that if you run from XCode they aren't limited but in practice I've found that even in development some may be ignored; if you've been testing various things it's possible they're being discarded. If you keep the system log open there will be a line stating that the message was received but throttled if this is the case.
You can look

Comment: @nvoigt I'm following this https://github.com/sbis04/notify

Comment: Where exactly are you testing this? On a real device or in the simulator?

Comment: @nvoigt real device, incoming notification when the application is open, if the application is closed the notification does not appear

Comment: @nvoigt I've also tried using testflight